# (Need Help) Using OnClickListener in Fragment, On Button Click App Force Closes

Tags: java, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I am trying to make an temperature converter.
this is a tab fragment class. i have xml specified for this. which includes a button with android:onClick="onClick"

Here is the   TempFragment.java class source.
when i click on button the app force closes. 
Please help Debug

```
package com.example.converter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TempFragment extends Fragment 
  implements OnClickListener 
  {
  private EditText text;
  Button b;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_temp, container, false);
    text = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    b = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);         
    return view;

}

// this method is called at button click because we assigned the name to the
  // "OnClick property" of the button
  public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
      RadioButton celsiusButton = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio0);
      RadioButton fahrenheitButton = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio1);
      if (text.getText().length() == 0) {
          Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter a valid number", 
                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
      }

      float inputValue = Float.parseFloat(text.getText().toString());
      if (celsiusButton.isChecked()) {
        text.setText(String
            .valueOf(ConverterUtil.convertFahrenheitToCelsius(inputValue)));
        celsiusButton.setChecked(false);
        fahrenheitButton.setChecked(true);
      } else {
        text.setText(String
            .valueOf(ConverterUtil.convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(inputValue)));
        fahrenheitButton.setChecked(false);
        celsiusButton.setChecked(true);
      }
      break;
    }
  } 
}
```

UPDATE: Red marked lines from Logcat Log

```
 
03-14 00:21:44.711: I/SurfaceTextureClient(2631): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5df0bd48) fps:1.99, dur:1003.79, max:501.96, min:501.83
03-14 00:21:45.218: V/Provider/Settings(2631): invalidate [system]: current 476 != cached 0
03-14 00:21:45.223: V/Provider/Settings(2631): from db cache, name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
03-14 00:21:45.224: D/AndroidRuntime(2631): Shutting down VM
03-14 00:21:45.224: W/dalvikvm(2631): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c59a8)
03-14 00:21:45.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2631): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-14 00:21:45.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2631): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-14 00:21:45.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at com.example.converterplus.TempFragment.onClick(TempFragment.java:46)
03-14 00:21:45.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
03-14 00:21:45.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17446)
03-14 00:21:45.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-14 00:21:45.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-14 00:21:45.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
03-14 00:21:45.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
03-14 00:21:45.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 00:21:45.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-14 00:21:45.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
03-14 00:21:45.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-14 00:21:45.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Supply us with the stack trace. That way we know right away what's wrong, instead of us having to read all your code. Just edit your question and paste your stacktrace.

Comment: sir i dont know what is 'stack trace'. I am new .pls

Comment: Just google "stacktrace" along with your editor. "eclipse stacktrace" or "logcat eclipse" - then click on the image tab and you will have thousands of answers. Example. https://www.google.se/search?q=eclipse+stacktrace&num=20&client=firefox-a&hs=aHC&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=sb&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=Y_whU-fFB7CM4gT20oHICQ&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1540&bih=823

Comment: i updated those red marked lines from logcat log.. please check if i am correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE

You are getting a button in your view `onClick(View view){..}.` and your "radio0" is not defined in that view. You want `view` to be the layout view.

See code:

```
package com.example.converter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TempFragment extends Fragment 
  implements OnClickListener 
  {
  private EditText text;
  Button b;
  View view;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_temp, container, false);
    text = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    b = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);         
    return view;

}

// this method is called at button click because we assigned the name to the
  // "OnClick property" of the button
  public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
      RadioButton celsiusButton = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio0);
      RadioButton fahrenheitButton = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio1);
      if (text.getText().length() == 0) {
          Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter a valid number", 
                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
      }

      float inputValue = Float.parseFloat(text.getText().toString());
      if (celsiusButton.isChecked()) {
        text.setText(String
            .valueOf(ConverterUtil.convertFahrenheitToCelsius(inputValue)));
        celsiusButton.setChecked(false);
        fahrenheitButton.setChecked(true);
      } else {
        text.setText(String
            .valueOf(ConverterUtil.convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(inputValue)));
        fahrenheitButton.setChecked(false);
        celsiusButton.setChecked(true);
      }
      break;
    }
  } 
}
```

OLD:

If I get this correct, it's line no 46 that's crashing:

```
if (celsiusButton.isChecked())
```

which means you are not finding your celsiusButton at

```
RadioButton celsiusButton = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio0);
```

You can step down to line no 46 in your code and double check this.

If it's the correct line then you need to double check if your button is called "radio0" in your xml.

Comment: i cheked them its ok. Actually i have copied the code from a activity class which was working fine.. now when in fragment the layout is ok but not functioning.

Comment: Many many thanks.. your code is working. thanks for helping this noob.. may i reach you on any messenger( gtak, FB, Whatsapp )? will not disturb you every now and then promise.